# Given a user that has_many <model_name>, what is the correct way to find the user with the most <model_name>?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I am writing an app where each User has many posts. I would like to generate a top 3 list of the users with the most posts. The only way I can think of is to get all the posts and count how many each user has. This seems extremely expensive, and not scalable. Accuracy is important. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Post.group(:user_id).order("count_all DESC").limit(3).count`

should do the job. It groups the posts by the user, orders them after the number of posts and returns just the 3 with the most posts. the sql query may be more easy to understand:

`(0.3ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) AS count_all, user_id AS user_id FROM "posts" GROUP BY user_id ORDER BY count_all DESC LIMIT 3`

and rails returns for you a hash like this:

`{user_id => number_of_posts, user_id => number_of_posts, user_id => number_of_posts}`

Comment: Thanks. That is a so cool, I had no idea you could do it like that.

Answer (score 2):

You're probably looking for a counter_cache here: check out the [ActiveRecord association documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html). Essentially, if you have a posts_count integer column with a default of 0 on the users table and set :counter_cache to true in the association, Rails will update the column automatically. Then you can just do something like `User.order('posts_count DESC').limit(3)` to get the users with the most posts.