# Rails MySQL and PostgreSQL order by number of associted items

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Konkurrencer has many kliks

and

kliks belongs_to :konkurrencer

How do I order by the number of associted kliks?

Example:

```
Konkurrencer.find(:all, :order => 'by counted kliks')
```

I know to add a counter cache column. Just want to know how to do such a query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I answered a question like this once: take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9558901/given-a-user-that-has-many-model-name-what-is-the-correct-way-to-find-the-use/9559115#9559115).

In your case it should be a bit easier:

```
Konkurrencer.group(:kliks_id).order("count_all DESC").count
```

This will return a hash with the ID of the `Konkurrencer` as key and the number of `Kliks` as value.